# Xamarin Appium perform search on Android and iOS by pressing softkeys

Tags: java, selenium, automation, appium

I am working on Automating Xamrin Android and iOS App using Appium.
In one of the Tests, I need to search from the text box to get the list of results.

On iOS `element.sendkeys("Some Text" + "\n")` seems to work fine.
But on Android, it is not working.

For Android, I tried

```
someMethod(){
 element.sendkeys("Some Text");
 element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

but this will delete the entered text and add an additional single Chinese character in the search box.

Any suggestions on how to Enter text and perform a search that would work on both Android and iOS for an app built on Xamarin

Comment: Have tried `element.submit()` ?

Comment: On using submit getting error :Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <unknown method, unsupported operation>